# add items to a list if the list is not long enough

Tags: python, list

I have a list of lists and I need to check if all the nested lists have a length of 5.

if the nested list doesn't have 5 items I need to add some placeholders ---

the bit of code below works but it feels like this could be done better.

```
result2 = []
result3 = []    
for i in infos:
        if len(i)== 5:
            result2.append(i)
        else:
            x = i
            test = check-len(i)
            lst = range(0,test)
            for l in lst:
                result3.append("---")
            x.extend(result3)
            result2.append(x)
            result3 = []
OUT = result2
```

Comment: Please consider to post your question on [CodeReview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com) if it is working but you are looking for general improvements. See their help pages for how to ask on-topic questions, though. For [SO], please consult the [ask] and [mcve] page how to ask a complete, specific on-topic question. "it feels like this could be done better" is an extremely vague problem description.

Comment: what if we have more than 5 entries?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work for your purposes. I find the code easier to organize as a list comprehension.

```
placeholder = '---'
result2 = [
    [(i[a] if len(i) < a else placeholder) for a in range(5)]
    for i in infos
]
```

Rather than explicitly checking for if any of your lists has length 5, we instead just build a new list of exactly five elements long, each element copying from `i` if possible or using `placeholder` if not.

There are a lot of ways you could also implement this. A construction more similar to @balderman's solution would look like this:

```
placeholder = '---'
result2 = [
    i if len(i) >= 5 else (i + ['---'] * (5 - len(i)))
    for i in infos
]
```

which takes `i` wholesale instead of copying it, if it's large enough, or uses list concatenation to append as many `'---'`s as necessary otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

see below - just little shorter

```
infos = [[1, 2], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [55, 55, 55, 55, 55, 55, 99]]
padded_infos = []
for entry in infos:
    if len(entry) >= 5: # what about the case where we have more than 5 elements in a sub list?
        padded_infos.append(entry)
    else:
        delta = 5 - len(entry)
        for x in range(delta):
            entry.append('---')
        padded_infos.append(entry)
print(padded_infos)
```

output

```
[[1, 2, '---', '---', '---'], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [55, 55, 55, 55, 55, 55, 99]]
```

Comment: Note how ``padded_infos.append(entry)`` is identical in both branches. You can always append the entry, and only run the second branch conditionally.